# Is it possible to use MMC 4bit on ESP32?

Tags: esp32, sd, mmc

I'm trying to connect an SDCard to an ESP32 and need more than the regular SPI reading speed. I've seen that the board supports one MMC channel of 1/4 bits (it actually has another channel which is reserved to internal flash memory use).

I'm using a micro SDCard adaptor which I've soldered wires to the pads. Checked connectivity and "cross-connectivity" and everything looks fine as far as I can tell.
I'm following the pin assignment [here](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.SDCard.html#esp32), and tried to initialize the board with the following code:

```
import os
from machine import SDCard, Pin

sdc = SDCard(slot=1, width=4)
os.mount(sdc, "/sd")
print(os.listdir("sd"))
```

With `width=1` it works correctly after I added an external 10k pull-up resistor on GPIO2 (D0). When I try `width=4` I always get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
OSError: 16
```

It's the same card and same connections. I've also added 10k pull-ups on all 6 lines (4 x DATA, CMD, CLK). It didn't help.

I'm suspecting GPIO12 (D2) as it's described [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-pinout-reference-gpios/) as `boot fails if pulled high, strapping pin`. I'm assuming that there is an internal pull-down resistor on this leg?

If so - Can I use it for the MMC? Can I switch to a different GPIO for D2?
I guess I'm missing something, otherwise I can't see why would they choose a pin that can't be used..

Comment: It is possible that the ESP32 chip itself has taken this confusing situation into account, but the board designer may not have. What ESP32 board are you using, or have you designed one yourself?

Comment: Good idea... I'm using one of these: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001636295529.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.10.49381802Tst6GE 
but I couldn't find a schematics anywhere... I can order a different kind, but what should I look for?